# SPARQL query doesn't give any results

Tags: rdf, sparql, ontology, fuseki

I'm trying to run a SPARQL query on a local ontology using Fuseki, but I'm unable to get any results. My ontology contains a list of countries like this:

```
###  http://localhost:2020/country/6

<http://localhost:2020/country/6> rdf:type <http://localhost:2020/vocab/country> , owl:NamedIndividual ;
rdfs:label "country #6" ;
<http://localhost:2020/vocab/country_id> 6 ;
<http://localhost:2020/vocab/country_name_nl> "Nederland" ;                              
<http://localhost:2020/vocab/country_code> "nl" .
```

And properties are like this one:

```
###  http://localhost:2020/vocab/country_code

<http://localhost:2020/vocab/country_code> rdfs:label "country code" .
```

The test query I'm trying to run is:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?name WHERE {?name rdfs:type <http://localhost:2020/vocab/country>} LIMIT 50
```

Why doesn't this give me a list of countries? I'm getting an empty "name" column instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silly mistake, 'type' is rdf and not rdfs... Works like a charm now!

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
SELECT ?name WHERE {?name rdf:type <http://localhost:2020/vocab/country>} LIMIT 50
```